# Does this look like a good way to use a class?

Tags: python, class, variables, initialization, instance-variables

I have a class, and a Python script that calls functions from the class.

The class is called `User_Input_Test`. The script is called `input_test.py`.

`input_test.py` will request input from the user by using one of the class functions/methods: `get_user_input(self)`. It is then supposed to print out whatever the user entered, through the use of the second function/method called `show_output(self)`.

It generates an error:

```
User_Input_Test.show_output()\
  File "/Users/michel/Python_Projects/User_Input_Test.py", line 49, in show_output\
    """)
AttributeError: type object 'User_Input_Test' has no attribute 'brand'
```

It looks like `show_output(self)` is not able to see the data pulled in from the user via `get_user_input(self)`.

Would you say that is the correct interpretation of the error? And most importantly: Is there a solution for this, or am I trying to use a class for something it was never designed for?

`user_input.py`:

```
from User_Input_Test import User_Input_Test
import time

#User_Input_Test.__init__(self, name, brand, engine, doors, fuel_type, aircon, weight, mpg, tax)

print("This little application collects data about your car")
print("Please fill out the following questionnaire:")
uname = input("What is your first name?:")
User_Input_Test.get_user_input()

print(f"{uname}, these are your car's attributes: ")
time.sleep(2)

User_Input_Test.show_output()
```

`User_Input_Test.py`

```
class User_Input_Test:
    """
    Small Class that asks the user for their car attributes and can print them out
    Attributes:
        brand(string)
        engine(string)
        ....
    """

    def __init__(self, brand, engine, doors, fuel_type, aircon, weight, mpg, tax):
        self.brand = brand
        self.engine = engine
        self.doors = doors
        self.fuel_type = fuel_type
        self.aircon = aircon
        self.weight = weight
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.tax = tax

    @classmethod
    def get_user_input(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                brand = input("What is the Brand & Model of your car? (e.g. 'Mercedes Benz, E-Class'):    ")
                engine = input("Engine Cylinders and Displacement (e.g. '4 Cylinders, 2.1 Liters'):    ")
                doors = input("How many doors does it have?:    ")
                fuel_type = input("What fuel does it use? (e.g. Petrol, Diesel, LPG):    ")
                aircon = input("Does it have Airconditioning? (Yes/No):    ")
                weight = input("How much does it weight in KG? (e.g. 1800kg):    ")
                mpg = input("What is the fuel consumption in Imperial MPG? (e.g. 38mpg):    ")
                tax = input("How much does the UK Roadtax cost per year? (e.g. £20):    ")
                return self(brand,engine,doors,fuel_type,aircon,weight,mpg,tax)
            except:
                print('Invalid input!')
                continue
            
    def show_output(self):
        print(f"""
==========================================================================
    Brand Name:.......................  {self.brand}
    Engine:...........................  {self.engine}
    Number of Doors:..................  {self.doors}
    Fuel Type used by the engine:.....  {self.fuel_type}
    Does it have Aircon?:.............  {self.aircon}
    Fuel consumption in Imperial MPG:.  {self.mpg}
    Cost of Road Tax per Year:........  {self.tax}
==========================================================================
        """)
```

Comment: You're not saving the instance created, then call an instance method on the class. Try `car = User_Input_Test.get_user_input()` (and note classes should be `PascalCase`, in this case just `Car`).

Comment: It is a bit unusual for a class to ask input from the user. You may rather get data from input and call the class constructor (__init__) with them. You also have to create the car objet. ex: car = User_Input_Test(...)

Comment: @Malo having a `@classmethod` as an alternate constructor is quite a common pattern, it *does* get data from the input then call `__init__` (`self` in a class method is more conventionally named `cls`, to make it clear it's the *class* not the *instance*). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31011502/3001761, or think about built-ins like `dict.fromkeys`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was not commenting about the @classmethod, just about asking for direct user input in it. It may be less resusable this way. You link is fine for me, and shows no direct "input" instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User_Input_Test.show_output()` tries to call `show_output` on the class itself; you need to call it on the instance returned by `User_Input_Test.get_user_input()`.

```
from User_Input_Test import User_Input_Test
import time

print("This little application collects data about your car")
print("Please fill out the following questionnaire:")
uname = input("What is your first name?:")
car = User_Input_Test.get_user_input()

print(f"{uname}, these are your car's attributes: ")
time.sleep(2)

car.show_output()
```

Note: check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, notably the naming conventions for modules and classes. In this case, I would name the module `car` and the class `Car` for more clarity and better style. Also, the argument to a `classmethod` is usually named `cls`, as `self` is conventionally reserved for the instance in normal methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! :D 

It makes a lot more sense now, after I created the instance, because that allows it to store the data collected during the input function.